# DART passing parameter to SelectElement / OptionElement

Tags: dart, dart-html

I made this as OptionElement in DART, which was fine:

```dart
   var source = new SelectElement()
             ..children.add(new OptionElement(value: 'vCode', data:'myVendor Name'));
```

I want to take my vendor list as call back from the server, and put then in the select option so the user can select the vendor code/name, I made the returned Map from the server as `{"code":"vCode","name":"myVendor Name"}`, and wanted to add them using a loop, I tried the below but did not work::

```dart
var vendor = <Map>[];   

for(int i=0;i<=number_of_vendors;i++){
     var source = new SelectElement()
             ..children.add(new OptionElement(value: vendor[i]['code'], data: vendor[i]['name']));
}
```

any though?
thanks

Comment: For me it's not clear what you want to do in a loop.

Comment: I tuned the question, hope it is more clear now.

Comment: To make this code work you need to get a list of maps `[{"code":"vCode1","name":"myVendor Name1"},{"code":"vCode2","name":"myVendor Name2"}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't work

```dart
var source = new SelectElement()
         ..children.add(new OptionElement(value: "$vendor['code']", data:"$vendor['name']"));
```

you can do either

var source = new SelectElement()
             ..children.add(new OptionElement(value: vendor['code'], data:vendor['name']));

if `vendor['code']` and `vendor['name']` return a string or

var source = new SelectElement()
             ..children.add(new OptionElement(value: "${vendor['code']}", data:"${vendor['name']}"));

When after the `$` comes a simple identifier you can omit the curly braces, if it is an expression you need to add them.

#### Update - the code actually used provided by @Hasan A Yousef

Below code should work fine.

```dart
   var vendors = <Map>[];
```

then

```dart
       vendors=[{"code":"vCode1","name":"myVendor Name1"},{"code":"vCode2","name":"myVendor Name2"}];
```

or

```dart
       vendors.add({"code":"vCode 1","name":"vName 1"}); 
       vendors.add({"code":"vCode 2","name":"vName 2"});
       vendors.add({"code":"vCode 3","name":"vName 3"}); 
       vendors.add({"code":"vCode 4","name":"vName 4"});
```

followed by:

```dart
   for(int i=0;i<vendors.length;i++){
       source..children.add(new OptionElement(value: vendors[i]['code'], data: vendors[i]['name']));
   }
```

or by:

```dart
  for(Map vendor in vendors){
    source..children.add(new OptionElement(value: vendor['code'], data: vendor['name']));
  }
```

Comment: In both ways, I got: 'Map<dynamic, dynamic> vendor, only static members can be accessed in initializer,

Comment: This is because you have this code outside of a method. You can leave `var source` where it is but the rest of the code should be moved to the constructor.

Comment: thanks, it is fine now :) I tuned your answer to reflect the statements worked with me.